# Ajax Calendar validations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax, validation

In my web application I have taken a ajax calendar in that i want to restrict the user to select future date, when user select future date should raise the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use compare validator and set its type to Date

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cmp" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CompareValidator"
        Operator="LessThanEqual" Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

In the codebehind set ValuetoCompare like.

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        cmp.ValueToCompare = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
    }
```

Comment: hello there, now if I want to add some more like whatever the date selected I want to add 7months and 2days with that and display it in another texbox..now how to do that? 
thanks you